# With the new REST API do users have to leave your site to confirm their payment?

Tags: javascript, paypal

**Update:** Okay, so it's been a long day, and it's getting to be a late night. It seems a normal credit card charge doesn't require any redirect to paypal. Here's the link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#redirecturls-object

From this page: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

> Get payment approval
>
> Take note of the HATEOAS links in the example above. Direct the user
>   to the approval_url on PayPal so that the user can approve payment.
>   The user must approve the payment before you can execute and complete
>   the sale.

I read that the user must be directed to PayPal. The whole reason I want to use the REST API is to never redirect my user to PayPal. This kind of defeats the purpose. Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: I haven't tried the REST method. The method that we are using to let the user stays on our site during payment processing to PayPal is "Adaptive"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your observation. We are working on the solutions to support the experience you are looking for. As Jobert mentioned, I would recommend using the classic Adaptive Payments API until then. We will keep you updated when we add new experiences to the REST api.

Comment: If the user wants to pay with their paypal account, it's actually totally fine to send them along to paypal. For me anyways. I was worried I'd have to send normal credit card payments to paypal for approval.

Comment: if you've PCI compliant server, you can use the REST api to process direct Credit Card payments. In which case you don't need to send them to PayPal. The PayPal redirect is only required when your user wants to Pay with PayPal account.